# How to export special characters from illustrator to word

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, microsoft-word

The problem is I want to get some specific special characters from SVN-Bellico font like the `H` below. I could use it in Illustrator but I want to use them in MS Word to be able to edit them.

[image: SVN-Bellico]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are ***glyphs*** in the font definitions - they are coded into the font as designed - Illustrator and InDesign and other similar tools can show you a happy overview of all available **glyphs** in a font, and in fact your OS can too (Windows it's called Character Map, in Mac OS (at the moment) it's called Special Characters or Show Emoji & Symbols) and you can "use" them in any program in which fonts can be used, assuming you can come up with a way to place them into your given document's text-stream. If there's no way within the app, you can use the OS-level tools I already mentioned to add them to a text string manually.

However, I've *another* concern here - your written phrase in your question:

> "...but I want to use them in MS Word *to be able to **edit** them*..."

You can **write with them** - include them in a text-string in Word document - but you *cannot* ***edit*** them in Word - you'd need a font authoring tool to edit the glyphs included in a given font.

If you want to *visually* edit a glyph in a *one-off manner* (not altering the font file but just a specific instance in a single document) by say stretching a curve, altering a ligature etc - that's best done in Illustrator or other similar vector design software by converting the text into vector curves and editing them as you would any other graphic element.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I know a workaround. To visually edit the vector shape in word, do the following:

1. Type your character in illustrator.
2. Convert to outline
3. Export as a .wmf (or .emf)
4. In Word, *Insert > Picture* and choose your exported file
5. Right Click your image, *Group > Ungroup* to convert it to a Microsoft Drawing Object
6. Right Click again and choose *Edit Points*

But as Gerard said, you have much more control over the vector in Illustrator.

Hope this helps!